# How do i compress multiple folders into zipped folders without creating subfolders?

Tags: 7zip

I am trying to compress multiple folders (about 100) into individual zipped folders. I did this by making a .bat file like so - for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X"
My problem is that it makes a folder inside the zipped folder, but I need it to just compress the insides of the folder into a zipped folder. I can compress the content of each folder individually but that would take hours. If anybody knows how to do this I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Use at end `"%%X\"` which is interpreted like `"%%X\*"` to reference all files and folders inside the folder of which path is assigned to loop variable `X` instead of `"%%X"` which references the folder itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for /D %%X in (*) do c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"%%X.zip" ".%%X*"

pause

just needed to add .\ to to "%%X" (from "%%X" to ".%%d*")